# How can I describe a sequence diagram message which could be disabled or enabled by pre-processor in a sequence diagram

Tags: c, uml, sequence-diagram

I am currently drawing a sequence diagram for a module spec document.

The reason I am considering is that I don't know how to describe conditional compile code in a sequence diagram.

for example,

```
void func_A( void )
{
#if (A == Yes)
    func_B();
#endif
}
```

in this code, func_B is compiled if A is Yes, but can not be compiled if A is No.

How can I draw a sequence diagram with that kind of code?

Comment: func_b will always be compiled it will just not be called. This is a normal if just that you make it dependent on a macro instead of a variable (for what ever reason) This looks like bad design, but maybe it is more complicated...

Comment: Oh, Yes. funb_B will always be compiled but not called. I programmed kind of common code to use in every project, and the code can be configured by macro. so that I can spare time..

Comment: See https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html#operator-opt

Comment: @xmojmr I thought about that, but this is no runtime condition. Actually it's a different object as tofro answered.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional compilation actually builds *two different* programs with two different settings of your preprocessor switch.

There is no foreseen way to be able to put two programs in one sequence diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what @tofro answered. You can create 2 different SDs where one could look like this:

[image]

and the other just without the `func_B` call and an adapted note.